# How do I get software to show up in Ubuntu Software?

Tags: package-management, software-center, aptitude

I used an earlier version of Ubuntu, and the Software program listed pretty much all available software in the repos.  Having a fresh 17.04 install, there is surprisingly less showing up.

Worrying that I was missing some repos, I checked Settings>Software and Updates to see that all the repos were checked active.  I dropped to a terminal and installed aptitude, and there's oodles of software that I would expect to show up in Ubuntu Software that just doesn't.

One example was the Gramps genealogy package, which didn't show up even with a search for "gramps" in the Ubuntu Software Program. It showed up and installed flawlessly from aptitude. Oddly enough, after I installed it, it showed up as installed in Ubuntu Software.

What do I need to do to make Ubuntu Software show all the software that is available?